# Pegar HTML com jQuery ao apertar botão

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Tenho um sistema simples que pega o HTML de um arquivo e o coloca em uma *index* única e dinâmica. Exemplo:

```
<a onclick="carregar('cartaonatal/natal.html');" href="#">Agradecimento</a>

//chama a função

function carregar(pagina){
    $("#conteudo").load(pagina);
}
```

O HTML carregado é colocado dentro da `div` `#conteudo`. O que eu queria é que carregasse um *load* ou imprimisse na `div` com alguma animação visual simples.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Se achou a resposta útil, não deixe de marcar ✔

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue utilizando `.fadeOut` com *callback*, e em seguida com `.fadeIn()` do próprio elemento com outro *callback* do `.load()`:

```
function carregar(pagina){
   $('#conteudo').fadeOut(function(){
       $(this).load(pagina, function(){
           $(this).fadeIn();
       });
   });
}
```